# Tkinter, printing result in scrolled window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have generate tkinter code using PAGE, and i have scrolledlistbox there,
part of the code where i am adding text:

```
class New_Toplevel:
  def __init__(self, top=None):
    self.Scrolledlistbox1.insert(0,"my text")
```

and `my text` is printed inside this scrolled window in GUI.
I need to print inside this window result from my definition :

```
def MYdef():
    MYdef.file="another text"
```

When i am trying to get this variable from definition inside the window like this:

```
class New_Toplevel:
  def __init__(self, top=None):
    self.Scrolledlistbox1.insert(0,MYdef.file)
```

i am receiving :

error:

```
self.Scrolledlistbox1.insert(0,RUN.file)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'file'
```

EDIT:
 i have changed last line:

```
class New_Toplevel:
  def __init__(self, top=None):
    self.Scrolledlistbox1.insert(1,MYdef())
```

Result is printed in console but still not inside the scrolled window in GUI, how to do it correctly? Also after clicking the button result should be shown in window not earlier;/
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you never called `MYdef()`, so it never had a chance to set the `file` attribute.  Assigning it *outside* of the function might work, although there is probably a better way to accomplish whatever your actual goal is here.

Comment: Change `MYdef.file="another text"` to `file="another text"`

Comment: What does "using PAGE" mean? Is PAGE an acronym for some open source tool?  Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @jasonharper what you mean? any example?
Billal BEGUERADJ if i will do that, this file could be used only inside this specific definition.
Bryan Oakley PAGE its a gui generator

Comment: by the way, `0` is not a valid text widget index. Valid indexes are strings of the form _line.character_. The first line is `1`, and the first character is `0`, making the very first index `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved that problem by copy `self.Scrolledlistbox1.insert(1,"MY INFO")` inside each definition where i want to print results from them